# why is R9 390 using radeon instead of amdgpu driver?

Tags: drivers, 16.04, amd-graphics

My R9 390 is using the open source radeon driver instead of the amdgpu driver. When first installing my system the "xserver-xorg-video-radeon" wasnt even installed. it was just the libs which seem to be tied to other dependencies. So i just decided to install the whole package anyway. Which i can uninstall still... but it still wont switch to amdgpu for some reason.

I would like to know how i can get my R9 390 to use the amdgpu drivers.

also i am using 16.04 LTS

```
sudo lspci -nnv -s
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Hawaii PRO [Radeon R9 290/390] [1002:67b1] (rev 80) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Tul Corporation / PowerColor Radeon R9 390 [148c:2358]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 134
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=8M]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
    Memory at dfe00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Capabilities: [150] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [200] #15
    Capabilities: [270] #19
    Capabilities: [2b0] Address Translation Service (ATS)
    Capabilities: [2c0] #13
    Capabilities: [2d0] #1b
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon


sudo dpkg -l | grep amdgpu
ii  libdrm-amdgpu1:amd64                                            2.4.68+git1606141830.625d18~gd~x         amd64        Userspace interface   to amdgp-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  libdrm-amdgpu1:i386                                             2.4.68+git1606141830.625d18~gd~x         i386         Userspace interface   to amdgp-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu 1.1.99+git1606281932.a57643~gd~x          amd64 X.Org X server -- AMDGPU display driver

sudo dpkg -l | grep radeon
pi  libdrm-radeon1:amd64                                            2.4.68+git1606141830.625d18~gd~x         amd64        Userspace interface   to radeo-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  libdrm-radeon1:i386                                             2.4.68+git1606141830.625d18~gd~x         i386         Userspace interface   to radeo-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  xserver-xorg-video-radeon 1:7.7.99+git1606280732.3be841~gd~x        amd64 X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI Radeon display driver

sudo uname -r
4.6.3-040603-generic
```

Comment: Support of this adapter by `amdgpu` is not reliable and it is disabled in the kernel.

Comment: Then where is the fully supported list and any information on when it might be not disabled?

Comment: For instance https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Amdgpu You can enable it manually by re-compiling the kernel. I do not think they will enable it in Ubuntu by default.